# How does the connection between CloudFront and one EC2 origin works using HTTPS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, https, amazon-cloudfront

Let's assume we have a domain *example.com* pointing to an EC2 instance, that allows HTTPS and HTTP (redirection to HTTPS) traffic.

This instance has a WordPress instance running under Nginx.

We have a certificate for the domain example.com, not self-signed, a Comodo certificate.

We want to add CloudFront to the full *example.com*, so we create a CDN between the user and the EC2 instance.

We could use the site *example.com* with/without CDN, by having two endpoints serving the same content (*example.com* and *origin.example.com*).
 
Without CDN:

> User -> example.com -> Route 53 pointing directly to instance IP (that has the Comodo certificate).

With CDN

> User -> example.com -> Route 53 pointing to ALIAS CDN -> CDN pull from origin origin.example.com

*origin.example.com* will have the same content than example.com (both Nginx hosts pointing the same), and there we should allow only traffic from the CDN, but this is a different topic.

To achieve this, we create another endpoint, *origin.example.com*, with a self-signed certificate (using let's encrypt), placed in the same server (same IP address).

The idea is to send the traffic from the CDN to *origin.example.com*, and from there fetch the content.

This CDN has its own *example.com* SSL certificate generated by Amazon and has as origin *origin.example.com*. It also has the Host header whitelisted, and the CNAME origin.example.com added.

Everything works as expected. If you visit example.com, you get the content from the CDN.

The problem? If you check the instance logs (bot *example.com* and *origin.example.com* are set in the same EC2 instance), the CDN is NOT calling *origin.example.com*, as it would be expected, it is calling ALWAYS *example.com*. How is it possible?

I set Logs for the CloudFront, and in this logs are like:

> 2019-01-10    15:35:47    MAD50   27633   83.59.32.239    GET xxxxxx.cloudfront.net   /mycontent/ 200 https://example.com/lalala  -   -   Miss    5o…nX1hEbw==    example.com https   566 0.140   -   TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 Miss    HTTP/2.0    -   -

I think this is due to the Host whitelisted field.

So, looks like the CloudFront sends the request to *origin.example.com*, but the Host header is set to *example.com*. So Nginx, somehow, parses the value in the *example.com* virtual host (as it is shown in the Logs, where you can see that the traffic comes from Amazon CloudFront). What is wrong here?

How CloudFront performs the connection?

What I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is behaving as expected.

When the `Host` header is whitelisted for forwarding, CloudFront still *connects to the origin* using the Origin Domain Name for the DNS lookup, but the `Host` header is not changed to match the Origin Domain Name as it is by default -- instead, it is copied from the original request sent by the browser, because that is (essentially) the purpose of whitelisting this header.  (Whitelisting a header also adds the header to the cache key for the request, so requests where only the incoming `Host` header differs will be considered distinct when that header is whitelisted.)  If not whitelisted, then the `Host` header sent to the origin is set by CloudFront to the value of Origin Domain Name.

For HTTPS from CloudFront to the Origin, CloudFront sets the SNI (during TLS negotiation with the origin) to the value it has chosen for the `Host` header using the rules, above, and requires the origin server to return a certificate matching that value.

This means that if the `Host` header is not whitelisted, then the origin server must have a certificate matching the Origin Domain Name, but if the `Host` header is whitelisted in the settings of the Cache Behavior that is handling a request, then CloudFront requires your origin server to supply a certificate matching the incoming `Host` header, *not* the Origin Domain Name.

If the appropriate rule is not matched, [the request fails with `502 Bad Gateway`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-custom-origin.html), because CloudFront considers the origin to be misconfigured since the connection is not secure when there is a certificate mismatch.

[What CloudFront does with request headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior) that are not whitelisted depends on the specific header.  Many (such as `Referer`) are dropped from the request, but some (like `Host` and `User-Agent`) are rewritten, and others (like `Content-Length`) pass through anyway.  The default actions are based on the purpose of the header, and these rules are designed for correct behavior and optimal caching.

Comment: Thanks! That is a brilliant answer! Does it mean then, that I would not need to set up origin.example.com ? I mean, if I understood your explanation, I could set as origin the EC2 DNS name ec2-****.compute-1.amazonaws.com, and use the same example.com SSL certificate that I had installed when I was pointing the domain directly to the EC2 instance. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can set it up that way, with one caveat that the system-assigned `dzczcexample.cloudfront.net` hostname can't be used for testing, because your origin certificate will of course never match that.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot not sure about that: Also, for HTTPS: if the Host header is whitelisted, then CloudFront allows your origin server to use a certificate matching either the Host header or the Origin Domain Name.

From the documentation you linked:  In addition, if you configured CloudFront to forward the Host header to your origin, the origin must respond with a certificate matching the domain in the Host header.

So I think your answer is partially incorrect?

Comment: @Stephane, you're absolutely correct. Fixed.  I have no idea what I was thinking when I wrote that.  Thank you for your comment, and please feel free to let me know if you see anything else that needs attention.